# Windows 10 on Toshiba Satellite Pro laptop

Tags: windows-10, system-restore

The diplay on my laptop suddenly reduced in size, with a 2cm margin either side. Then, it suddenly filled the whole screen again, however, the image is stretched and distorted. This distortion is in all apps and websites.

When I try to run "System Restore", I get Error message 0x80070091. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

When you are on the desktop, showing your background wallpaper image, right-click anywhere (but the icons), select "Display settings" under the popup menu. Underneath the "Scale and layout" header, select 100% scaling, and for resolution choose either 1) the largest dimensions; or 2) the one that says (Recommended). If the screen stops working entirely, wait for 15 seconds for the screen to auto revert back to the prior working setting. If this seems to be the incorrect dimension, select "Revert", if it is correct select "Keep changes". If neither resolution works (no puns intended), try going through the list top to bottom until you are satisfied.